# Not able to record HP Webtour app using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, record

I am new to Jmeter and I took HP Loadrunner Webtour application for testing. I am not able to record the Webtour app using Jmeter.

I have already changed my settings for firefox browser to its proxy port where it will record the Jmeter scripts. I tried other web application and it is recording fine but not with WebTour application.

Any suggestions!!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My expectation is is that you didn't change settings under "No Proxy for" input. By default Firefox browser don't use proxy for local requests and HP Web Tour application runs on local Apache server. Make sure that "No Proxy for" is either empty or doesn't contain anything related to your computer hostname or IP address

[image: Firefox Proxy Settings]

If for some reason it doesn't help you can try out [JMeter Google Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-load-testi/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi?hl=en) which doesn't require any extra configuration and you don't need to worry about proxies and SSL certificates.

Comment: You are right. It is recording perfectly now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Please try following steps...

Webtour Settings:

---

1: Navigate to WebTour folder and locate and open httpd.config file;

1: Look for 'Listen Tag' > Add this line "ServerName 127.0.0.1"  > save. it should be as below

#Listen 12.34.56.78:80

ServerName 127.0.0.1

Listen 1080

2: Go back to WebTour folder, double click on "StartServer". The WebTour apache server will start, If there is any error, you will notice the error on the cmd.

3: If after clicking on "StartServer", CMD disappears, Right click on "StartServer" and run as administrator (If it didn't run then go to step 4)

4: Open CMD and navigate to web tour path > Type the command StartServer and hit enter like (D:\Automation\jmeter\Web Tours 1.0\WebTours\StartServer

Answer (score 0):

Firefox Settings:

1: Type about:config in the address bar > Enter > Accept

2: Now search for the following entity

a: network.http.accept-encoding.secure Make it to TRUE

b: network.proxy.allow_hijacking_localhost Make it to TRUE

3: Make sure the network setting is set to 127.0.0.1 port 8888